# When does a continuous function defined on a non-compact closed and bounded convex set has a fixed point?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

Is there any result in fixed point theory which will give the existence of a fixed point for a continuous function defined on a non-compact, closed and bounded convex set?

Comment: What about the unit ball in $\ell^2$?

Comment: I expect that many good topological spaces have a continuous map into itself without fixed points. Maybe there exists a topological space $X$  admitting only identical and constant continuous maps into itself, but this space should be rather exotic.

Comment: @ Alex Ravsky : I think you mean closed unit ball $\bar D$ in $\ell^2$. Since we have $(e_i)_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset \bar D$ and this sequence doesn't have any convergent subsequence, $\therefore \bar D$ is not sequentially compact, and hence not compact. So we have a closed, bounded and non-compact space $\bar D$ in $\ell^2$. Also using triangle inequality of norm the space $\bar D$ is convex. But what about fixed-points of any continuous function on $\bar D$?

Comment: Yes, this is a first non-trivial relevant question, which came to my mind. The answer should be known, but I don't know it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275890/how-to-define-continuous-f-b-rightarrow-b-without-fixed-points ?

Comment: Write Schauder fixed point theorem in Google.

Answer (score 1):

The contraction mapping theorem seems to do the job, without needing closedness nor convexity.

Comment: Its only for contraction mapping, but see the question, I am asking a general case "for any continuous function".

Comment: @supremum In general, continuous functions don't have fixed points, so *some* additional hypotheses are required.

Comment: @ Behaviour : I am asking for the *hypotheses* when the function is defined on a particular kind of space(non-compact,closed,bounded and convex). Hope you understand what I am asking.

Comment: @Tomás: That case is ruled out by the conditions of the question, because in a finite dimensional vector space, every closed bounded set is compact.

Comment: You are right @supremum . I deleted my comment and posted another in the question. Take a look on it.